# Get a value using a forloop

Tags: javascript

I have a code written that returns a json as below.

```
"aggrRes": {
"totalSize": 3,
"done": true,
"records": [
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "AggregateResult"
    },
    "expr0": "2019-02-25",
    "expr1": 40,
    "expr2": 27
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "AggregateResult"
    },
    "expr0": "2019-02-22",
    "expr1": 36,
    "expr2": 9
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "AggregateResult"
    },
    "expr0": "2019-02-21",
    "expr1": 38,
    "expr2": 12.5
  }
 ]
}
```

Using this json I want to create another json. and here the format should be something like below.

```
in forloop:
   dataset:
      dates:[get all expr0 for all 3 records],
      expr1:[get all expr1 for all 3 records],
      expr2:[get all expr2 for all 3 records]
```

Here the main part that I'm confused is on how can I do the below.

```
var agResp = this.total_info.aggrRes;
for(int i=0; i<records.size; i++){
console.log(agResp.records[0].expr**i**);
}
```

Here I want to get the **expr** value by looping on the `i` value, that will generate me **expr0**, **expr1** and **expr2** values.

Thanks

Comment: you mean your expr0, expr1 is dynamic? it can be upto n values? like expr11.....or is it limited to expr2 only?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @UbiquitousDevelopers, currently it is limited to expr0, expr1, expr2, but it _might_ go dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var records = aggrRes.records; // Store Records in a variable
var values = [];

records.forEach(record => {
  Object.keys(record).forEach(key => {
    if (values[key]) {
      values[key].push(record[key]);
    } else {
      values[key] = [record[key]];
    }
  });
});
console.log(values);
```

Will return something like this

```
attributes: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
expr0: (3) ["2019-02-25", "2019-02-22", "2019-02-21"]
expr1: (3) [40, 36, 38]
expr2: (3) [27, 9, 12.5]
```